# how to work with NavigationTabStrip with fragment and viewpager

Tags: android, android-fragments

who now how to use this library
https://github.com/Devlight/NavigationTabStrip
how to use fragment in  viewpager in this library
asked to owner but nothing answer 
https://github.com/Devlight/NavigationTabStrip/issues/39

Comment: Please be more specific as it's difficult to understand what needs to done and what problems are you facing. Also, post your code sample here so that it's easy for others to answer your query

Answer (score 0):

most of these libraries are not maintained anymore. I created an alternative library, highly customisable tab bar, to be used with view pager. I plan to add support for non-viewpager in the future.

[PagerTabIndicator](https://github.com/Crysis21/PagerTabIndicator)